# How can I retrieve an entry from /etc/passwd for a given username?

Tags: bash, unix

I have the file :  /etc/passwd and I have to select from this file the informations about an user that is passed as an argument ( the file contains users and some informations about them and i have to select only the information and print it).

Comment: Use `awk` with `:` as the field separator. Then search for the line where `$1 == username`

Comment: If your operating system provides `getent`, you should use *that* to search for user information. `getent passwd someuser` will extract the information about `someuser` for you -- but it'll even work if your system uses something other than `/etc/passwd`, like LDAP or NIS.

Answer (score 3):

#### As this question is tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), I could purpose:

```
getUserDetails() {
    local dir gid name pass shell uid user
    while IFS=':' read user pass uid gid name dir shell ;do
        [ "$user" = "$1" ] &&
            printf "    %-14s %s\n" User "$user" UID "$uid" GID "$gid" \
                "Full name" "$name" Directory "$dir" "Default shell" "$shell"
    done </etc/passwd
}

getUserDetails user
    User           user
    UID            1000
    GID            1000
    Full name      Linux User,,,
    Directory      /home/user
    Default shell  /bin/sh
```

#### or more [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) tool oriented:

```
declare -A UserDetail
getUserDetails() {
    local dir gid name pass shell uid user
    while IFS=':' read user pass uid gid name dir shell ;do
        [ "$user" = "$1" ] && UserDetail=( [user]=$user [name]=$name
                                           [dir]=$dir   [shell]=$shell
                                           [UID]=$uid   [GID]=$gid )
    done </etc/passwd
}

getUserDetail user
printf "The full name is: %s.\n" "${UserDetail[name]}" 
Linux User

declare -p UserDetail
declare -A UserDetail='([name]="Linux User,,," [user]="user" [GID]="1000" [shell]="/bin/sh" [dir]="/home/user" [UID]="1000" )'

paste <(printf "%s\n" "${!UserDetail[@]}") <(printf "%q\n" "${UserDetail[@]}")
name    Linux User\,\,\,
user    user
GID     1000
shell   /bin/sh
dir     /home/user
UID     1000
```

This way is very efficient, it set a *global* variable without forks.

Comment: The only change I might make for this is adding some additional quotes (ie. `echo "${UserDetail[name]}"`, so as not to expand any glob characters in the username field). Home directory, too, could possibly (however unlikely) include characters that could be mangled by expansion -- or perhaps even *would* be mangled, if something else in the OP's script set `IFS=/`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Right! But this come from far away! Ok I will add quotes.

Comment: The assignments, actually, you're OK without quotes -- it's the `printf` and `echo` arguments where that's not the case. (see `name='name with spaces'; declare -A arr; arr=( [name]=$name ); declare -p arr`).

Comment: It's entirely POSIX-specified that string-splitting and glob-expansion is suppressed on assignments.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy did you already use `paste <(printf "%s\n" "${!UserDetail[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${UserDetail[@]}")` ?

Comment: Heh -- cute! I haven't incorporated that into my body of idiom, but if we're certain values can't contain newline literals it's not a bad idea at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `UserDetail[test]=$'This string\ncontain newlines'` then `paste <(printf "%s\n" "${!UserDetail[@]}") <(printf "%q\n" "${UserDetail[@]}")`

Comment: Yup, with `%q` that's quite safe.